# Как лучше реализовать сетку для изменения свойства кликом

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, datagrid, grid

Нужно создать сетку и список c# wpf.
При клике на ячейку, присвоить значение (картинку,) вставлять картинку в клетки.
Добавлять удалять, колонки, строки.
Вопрос: как лучше реализовать?

Пробовал datagrid, так и не понял как с ним работать, даже с сайта msdn, пример для .net framework , не работает.
Может можно сгенерировать управляемую сетку по другому, или дайте руководство для datagrid.
Два дня в поисках.

Уточнение 1: Я не могу программно инициализировать datagrid и сгенерировать динамическую сетку,  10 строк, 10 колонок.

Связанные проблемы в реализации:
[Как привязать Itemsourse с DataTemplate в DataGrid](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1118424/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-source-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-image-datatemplate-%D0%B2-datagrid-wpf-c)

Comment: Вам нужна таблица как в экселе - тогда `DataGrid`. Если нужно просто сделать несколько кнопок в список, то [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61296541/how-to-bind-multiple-buttons-in-combobox/61298203#61298203) пример. Опишите подробнее, что вы хотите сделать, покажите код, который у вас не работает, добавьте его в вопрос.

Comment: Код я недобавляю, потому что , примеров кода очень много, и все не подходят.

Comment: Ну тогда я не знаю, как вам помочь. Конретики нет. Например, нарисуйте на бумажке, что вы хотите. Расскажите, какие данные хотите отображать. Чтобы что-то напрограммировать - нужно конкретизировать задачу.

Comment: Прочитал "уточнение", стало понятнее. Посмотрите [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1115005/datagrid-c-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d1%8f%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8e).