# DataGrid c#. Как вносить значения в ячейки пользователю?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Есть кнопка на создание матрицы. После ее создания, нужно заполнить клетки с клавиатуры. Для подтверждения данных есть кнопка "Ввести значения". Значения с таблицы записываются в массив nums.

Это создание матрицы:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            m = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            n = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);

            for (int i=0; i<m; i++)
            {
                DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn();
                Matrix.Columns.Add(column);
            }

            dynamic row = new ExpandoObject();

            for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
            {
                Matrix.Items.Add(row);
            }

            nums = new double[m, n];
        }
```

После создания матрицы пытаюсь вводить числа в ячейки, но программа завершает работу.
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Чтобы найти, где ошибка в программе - используйте [отладку](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019).

Сразу скажу, задача получилась нетривиальная, и букв в этом ответе будет много. **Пишу с нуля, потому что мой подход к решению несовместим с подходом автора вопроса.**

*Приложение создано на базе WPF **.NET Core 3.1**, но разницы с .NET Framework быть не должно.*

Пример привожу не для боевого проекта, а в целях обучения, чтобы можно было понять, как же именно победить `DataGrid` и сделать её матрицей, хотя сама `DataGrid` предназначена для работы со списком объектов, а не с двумерными массивами.

За основу для данных взял класс `System.Data.DataTable`, обычно его используют для получения и сохранения данных в БД SQL-типа. Так же он поддерживает динамическое обновление отображения данных в `DataGrid`, а это именно то, что нужно.

Для реализации примера я использовал шаблон программирования [**MVVM**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern) и следующее техническое задание (сам его себе придумал):

- Реализовать отображение матрицы в `DataGrid`, то есть двумерного числового массива
- Заголовки колонок и строк таблицы должны быть пронумерованы
- **[Ответ на главный вопрос]** Данные вводиться будут прямо в таблицу
- Чтобы не усложнять пример, пусть будет тип данных для каждой ячейки `int`
- Реализовать управление размером таблицы с минимальным размером 1x1
- Реализовать метод очистки таблицы для демонстрации команды, изменяющей таблицу
- Реализовать метод подсчета суммы всех ячеек для демонстрации способа использования данных

*Почему **MVVM**? Да потому что для реализации этого ТЗ методом Winforms с обработчиками событий, пришлось бы написать раз в 5 больше кода и воевать с попутными багами и странностями поведения контролов. WPF заточен под MVVM и нативно поддерживает такой подход, это удобно. Например, я написал 0 строк кода для валидации ячеек таблицы и текстовых полей (а валидация есть!), а кнопки сами дизаблятся, когда команду нельзя использовать. Другими словами - тратил время на написание полезного кода, а не костылей и обвязок.*

Для реализации примера по шаблону **MVVM** потребуется 2 вспомогательных класса, которые просто надо добавить в проект один раз "Правый клик на проекте -> Добавить -> Класс". Эти классы никогда не будут изменяться.

Первый из двух позволит сообщать интерфейсу о том, что какое-то свойство изменилось посредством вызова события `PropertyChanged`, которое в свою очередь я буду вызывать методом `OnPropertyChanged()`.

**NotifyPropertyChanged.cs**

```csharp
public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Так как в MVVM вообще не используются обработчики событий (за ненадобностью), нужно что-то, что можно вызывать когда например нажата кнопка - команду.

Второй вспомогательный класс как раз предназначен для удобного использования команд. Предлагаю на данном этапе не вникать в его код, а тоже просто добавить в проект.

**RelayCommand.cs**

```csharp
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    public void Execute(object parameter) => _execute(parameter);
}
```

Со вспомогательными классами покончено. Далее, нужно создать основной и самый нужный класс `MainViewModel`. Он и будет содержать нужные нам свойства и методы, и к нему будет подключен интерфейс приложения.

Привожу сразу полный код класса, в комментариях укажу возможно непонятные моменты, но кода не так много, думаю, разобраться вполне реально самостоятельно.

**MainViewModel.cs**

```csharp
public class MainViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DataTable _data;
    private ICommand _addRowCommand;
    private ICommand _addColumnCommand;
    private ICommand _removeRowCommand;
    private ICommand _removeColumnCommand;
    private ICommand _setSizeCommand;
    private ICommand _cleanCommand;
    private ICommand _calcSumCommand;
    private int _rowsCount;
    private int _columnsCount;
    private long _sum;

    public DataTable Data // контейнер для матрицы, DataGrid привязана сюда
    {
        get => _data;
        set
        {
            _data = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public int RowsCount // тексбокс Строки привязан сюда
    {
        get => _rowsCount;
        set
        {
            _rowsCount = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public int ColumnsCount // тексбокс Колонки привязан сюда
    {
        get => _columnsCount;
        set
        {
            _columnsCount = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public long Sum // число суммы ячеек привязано сюда
    {
        get => _sum;
        set
        {
            _sum = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void AddRows(int count) // добавить строки
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
            Data.Rows.Add();
        RowsCount = Data.Rows.Count;
    }
    private void AddColumns(int count) // добавить колонки
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
        {
            Data.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(Data.Columns.Count.ToString(), typeof(int))
            {
                AllowDBNull = false,
                DefaultValue = 0
            });
        }
        Data = Data.Copy(); // здесь и далее - хак, способ полностью перерисовать таблицу DataGrid, так как она не поддерживает динамическое изменение колонок.
        ColumnsCount = Data.Columns.Count;
    }
    private void RemoveRows(int count) // удалить строки (с конца)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= count && Data.Rows.Count > 1; i++)
            Data.Rows.RemoveAt(Data.Rows.Count - 1);
        RowsCount = Data.Rows.Count;
    }
    private void RemoveColumns(int count) // удалить колонки (с конца)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= count && Data.Columns.Count > 1; i++)
            Data.Columns.RemoveAt(Data.Columns.Count - 1);
        Data = Data.Copy();
        ColumnsCount = Data.Columns.Count;
    }

    // что делают команды, можно будет увидеть по биндингам на них у кнопок в xaml
    public ICommand AddRowCommand => _addRowCommand ?? (_addRowCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        AddRows(1);
    }));
    public ICommand AddColumnCommand => _addColumnCommand ?? (_addColumnCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        AddColumns(1);
    }));
    public ICommand RemoveRowCommand => _removeRowCommand ?? (_removeRowCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        RemoveRows(1);
    }, parameter => Data.Rows.Count > 1));
    public ICommand RemoveColumnCommand => _removeColumnCommand ?? (_removeColumnCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        RemoveColumns(1);
    }, parameter => Data.Columns.Count > 1));
    public ICommand SetSizeCommand => _setSizeCommand ?? (_setSizeCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        if (RowsCount > Data.Rows.Count)
            AddRows(RowsCount - Data.Rows.Count);
        if (RowsCount < Data.Rows.Count)
            RemoveRows(Data.Rows.Count - RowsCount);
        if (ColumnsCount > Data.Columns.Count)
            AddColumns(ColumnsCount - Data.Columns.Count);
        if (ColumnsCount < Data.Columns.Count)
            RemoveColumns(Data.Columns.Count - ColumnsCount);
    }));
    public ICommand CleanCommand => _cleanCommand ?? (_cleanCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Data.Rows.Count; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < Data.Columns.Count; j++)
                Data.Rows[i][j] = 0;
        Data = Data.Copy();
    }));
    public ICommand CalcSumCommand => _calcSumCommand ?? (_calcSumCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Data.Rows.Count; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < Data.Columns.Count; j++)
                sum += (int)Data.Rows[i][j];
        Sum = sum;
    }));

    public MainViewModel() // конструктор, выполняется 1 раз при запуске программы
    {
        Data = new DataTable();
        AddColumns(1);
        AddRows(1);
    }
}
```

И чтобы не заканчивать на полуслове, вот сразу полный код разметки. Обратите внимание, я нигде не использую именование `x:Name`. Оно без надобности, когда используются биндинги `Binding`. Грубо говоря, я сообщаю контролам, где брать данные, и они берут, сами, и сами обновляются.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xaml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/><!-- здесь поключается MainViewModel к интерфейсу -->
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Text="Строки   Колонки" Margin="5,5,5,0"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox Width="30" Margin="5" MaxLength="3" Text="{Binding RowsCount, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="×" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" Margin="0,0,0,4"/>
                <TextBox Width="30" Margin="5" MaxLength="3" Text="{Binding ColumnsCount, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <Button Content="Применить" Margin="5" Command="{Binding SetSizeCommand}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <Button Margin="5" Content="Добавить строку" Command="{Binding AddRowCommand}"/>
            <Button Margin="5" Content="Удалить строку" Command="{Binding RemoveRowCommand}"/>
            <Button Margin="5" Content="Добавить колонку" Command="{Binding AddColumnCommand}"/>
            <Button Margin="5" Content="Удалить колонку" Command="{Binding RemoveColumnCommand}"/>
            <Button Margin="5" Content="Очистить" Command="{Binding CleanCommand}"/>
            <Separator Margin="5"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Сумма всех ячеек:" Margin="5"/>
                <TextBlock Margin="0,5" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Sum}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Посчитать сумму" Margin="5" Command="{Binding CalcSumCommand}"/>
        </WrapPanel>
        <DataGrid Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell" AlternationCount="9999" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
                <ItemContainerTemplate>
                    <!-- AlternationIndex - это хак, использование не по назначению,
                    но здесь это самый простой способ пронумеровать строки без кучи кода -->
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding AlternationIndex,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}"/>
                </ItemContainerTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

В итоге, кода получилось не так много, и вроде все работает. Если есть дополнительные вопросы - задавайте в комментариях к этому ответу, помогу чем смогу.

[image: Скриншот]

Ну и традиционное, показываю для новичков в WPF **MVVM**, что же у меня в коде класса окна. А там ничего. :)

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```csharp
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```