# Как связать все колонки DataTable c DataGrid если используется DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid, datatable

Хотел отобразить все картинки в DataGrid которые хранятся в DataTabe как URI пути , в DataGrid  использовал свой шаблон ячейки (DataGridTemplateColumn) .
Думал что привязка будет к каждой колонке но удалось связать только по имени колонки.

Проблема в том что я не могу создать в DataTable колонки с одинаковыми именами.

```
      <DataGrid Name="ChannelDataGrid" Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" AutoGeneratingColumn="ChannelDataGrid_OnAutoGeneratingColumn" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell" AlternationCount="9999" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="ImgCell">
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=Img}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.Resources>

        <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
            <ItemContainerTemplate>
                <!-- AlternationIndex - это хак, использование не по назначению,
                но здесь это самый простой способ пронумеровать строки без кучи кода -->
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding AlternationIndex,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}"/>
            </ItemContainerTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
```

Как сделать binding к всем колонкам ?

**Обновление 1**:

Картинки есть но вся строка рисует картинки которые в первой ячейке, тоесть, можно менять картинки во всей строке а не ячейке.

```
            Data = new DataTable("BestTable");
        _data.Columns.Add("Img1");
```

И в XAML указал на неё.

```
        <DataGrid Name="ChannelDataGrid" Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" AutoGeneratingColumn="ChannelDataGrid_OnAutoGeneratingColumn" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell" AlternationCount="9999" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="ImgCell">
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=Img1}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.Resources>

        <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
            <ItemContainerTemplate>
                <!-- AlternationIndex - это хак, использование не по назначению,
                но здесь это самый простой способ пронумеровать строки без кучи кода -->
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding AlternationIndex,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}"/>
            </ItemContainerTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
```

Все последующие динамически созданные колонки и строки автоматически связывают их, но я не уверен что так правильно делать.

Код взять с [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1115005/datagrid-c-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8E) ответа.
Приложения на github https://github.com/Devoleksiy/MyApp3

Comment: Вы создаете шаблон `DataTemplate` с ключом `x:Key="ImgCell"`, то есть, добавляете его в справочник ресурсов, но нигде его не используете. Вам либо надо `DataType` прописать, либо разметить колонки явно.

Comment: у вас .NET Core или Framework?

Comment: Я вставил данный кусок кода из другого кода, но еще не разобрался как его упростить. Framework.  Разметить не могу,  колонки и ряды добавляются во время выполнения (Сетка для рисования картинками) . Подобный этому https://github.com/grebtsew/Patterns-Maker , но на wpf а не на windows form .