# Возможно ли вообще ввести в TextBox элементы двумерного массива?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int a = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    string[] numbers = textBox3.Text.Split(' ');

    if (a * a > numbers.Length)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Длина массива не соответсвует введенному!");
    }

    _array = new int[a, a];

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < numbers.Length; j++)
        {
            _array[i, j] = int.Parse(numbers[i]);
            label13.Text += Convert.ToString(numbers[i]) + "  ";
        }
        label13.Text += "\n";
    }
```

Это исключение, которое мне выбрасывает, когда я пытаюсь пройтись по длине `string[] numbers`:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: "Индекс находился вне границ массива."

Ввести, чтобы, например, (1, 2) вводилось как _array[0,0] _array[0,1]

Comment: [Смотрите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1115342/373567), какие штуки можно творить в WPF, в WinForms наверное тоже можно, но я бы не рискнул за полтора часа написать подобное. Показано, как можно вводить матрицу в `DataGrid` (аналог `DataGridView` в WinForms).

Comment: Была бы моя воля, но сказали сделать так...Спасибо за наводку буду рассматривать приложенную ссылку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
          _array[i / a, i % a] = int.Parse(numbers[i]);
          label13.Text += numbers[i] + "  ";
        }
        label13.Text += "\n";
```

Comment: Очень благодарю. Но не могли бы вы мне объяснить вот этот момент `_array[i / a, i % a]` ?

Comment: @qwerty `i / a` - вычисление номера строки двумерного массива по индексу одномерного через целочисленное деление. `i % a` - аналогично для номера столбца.