# При добавлении данных не обновляется DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Пытаюсь освоить WPF с паттерном MVVM
После добавления новых данных, не обновляется DataGrid.

Model:

```
public class ModelUser : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int _iduser;
        public string _secondname;
        public string _firstname;
        public string _middlename;
        public string _datebirth;
        public string _gender;
        public string _division;

        public int iduser
        {
            get { return _iduser;}
            set { _iduser = value; OnPropertyChanged("iduser"); }
        }
        public string secondname
        {
            get { return _secondname; }
            set { _secondname = value; OnPropertyChanged("secondname"); }
        }
        public string firstname
        {
            get { return _firstname; }
            set { _firstname = value; OnPropertyChanged("firstname"); }
        }
        public string middlename
        {
            get { return _middlename; }
            set { _middlename = value; OnPropertyChanged("middlename"); }
        }
        public string datebirth
        {
            get { return _datebirth; }
            set { _datebirth = value; OnPropertyChanged("datebirth"); }
        }
        public string gender
        {
            get { return _gender; }
            set { _gender = value; OnPropertyChanged("gender"); }
        }
        public string division
        {
            get { return _division; }
            set { _division = value; OnPropertyChanged("division"); }
        }

        public static List<ModelUser> GetUsers()
        {
            using (dbEntities db = new dbEntities())
            {
                var query = db.users.ToList().Join(db.division,
                        u => u.iddivision,
                        d => d.iddivision,
                        (u, d) => new ModelUser
                        {
                            iduser = u.iduser,
                            firstname = u.firstname,
                            secondname = u.secondname,
                            middlename = u.middlename,
                            gender = u.gender,
                            datebirth = u.datebirth.ToString("d"),
                            division = d.namedivision
                        }).ToList();

                return query;
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
```

VM:

```
  public class UserWindowMainModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ModelUser> UsersData { get; set; }

        public UserWindowMainModel()
        {
            UsersData = new ObservableCollection<ModelUser>(ModelUser.GetUsers());
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgUsers" 
                              HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                              Height="300" Margin="20,20,0,0"
                              Width="704"
                              CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
                              SelectionMode="Single" 
                              IsReadOnly="True" 
                              AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                              VerticalAlignment="Top"
                              VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UsersData}">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="30" Binding="{Binding iduser}" Header="№"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding secondname}" Header="Фамилия"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding firstname}" Header="Имя"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding middlename}" Header="Отчество"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding datebirth}" Header="Дата рождения"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding gender}" Header="Пол"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding division}" Header="Подразделение"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Добавление в таблицу:

```
private void buttAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (dbEntities db = new dbEntities())
            {
                    users users = new users
                    {
                        secondname = txtSecondName.Text.Trim(),
                        firstname = txtFirstName.Text.Trim(),
                        middlename = txtMidName.Text.Trim(),
                        datebirth = dpBirth.SelectedDate.Value,
                        gender = cbGender.SelectedValue.ToString(),
                        iddivision = int.Parse(cbDivision.SelectedValue.ToString())
                    };

                    db.users.Add(users);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    MessageBox.Show("Данные добавленны!", "Выполненно", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
```

Comment: При добавлении куда? Где это добавление?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ В таблицу. Добавил в вопрос добавление.

Comment: Нечнем с того, что `buttAdd_Click` — это не MVVM. Сама работа с базой данных по правилам MVVM должна быть отдельной моделью, а не постоянно инициализироваться в разных местах. `MessageBox` это, по сути, тоже нарушение MVVM и не стоит его использовать. Теперь сам вопрос - вы добавили в базу, но как эта база связана с вашей логикой? Вот есть у вас `ObservableCollection<ModelUser> UsersData`, с ней хоть какие либо манипуляции проходят? Я лично не вижу, вы раз загнали туда данные и все, а обновлять что в ней кто будет?)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  я не знаю как это сделать, поэтому и спрашиваю.

Comment: Не знаете что? Вот у вас есть два листа бумаги, на одном вы написали слово "Привет!", появиться ли это на другом листе? Наверно нет, а что бы это появилось, вам нужен некий механизм, который будет писать сразу на 2 листа, верно? Ну так и сделайте класс, который будет иметь метод добавления и в этом методе пусть он добавляет в коллекцию и в базу сразу, это будет модель взаимодействия с DB, ее и используйте везде, где надо.

Comment: Удалять и пересоздавать вопросы - не приветствуется на StackOverflow. Вам уже были даны ссылки на примеры ответов на подобные вопросы. Попробуйте вернуться к удаленному вопросу, заглянуть там в комментарии и еще раз попробовать ознакомиться с ответами по предоставленным ссылкам. Попробуйте сначала без БД, просто создайте ViewModel, засуньте туда `ObservableCollection`, добавьте в нее что-ниубдь, пусть даже в коде конструктора, и убедитесь что данные отображаются, и уже потом начнайте интеграцию с базой.

Comment: Вот вам [еще пример про MVVM](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1115342/373567)

Answer (score 0):

В кнопке вместо события и метода buttAdd_Click лучше использовать команду. Тогда это будет ложится под паттерн MVVM.
Выглядеть это будет примерно так:

XAML:

```
<Button Content="Добавить"
        Command="{Binding AddCommand}"/>
```

Далее в классе ViewModel создаёте свойство AddCommand, типа RelayCommand.

ViewModel.cs:

```
public RelayCommand AddCommand => new RelayCommand(AddMethod);
private void AddMethod(object obj)
{
    //метод добавления в таблицу...
    OnPropertyChanged("UsersData"); 
}
```

Класс RelayCommand реализует интерфейс ICommand. Как его реализовать есть в статье https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/22.3.php.
В метод AddMethod - вставь код, который выполнялся методом buttAdd_Click. В конце вызови метод обновления OnPropertyChanged.
Обрати внимание, что метод AddMethod должен принимать параметр типа object.