# Как сравнить данные в datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms

Помогите с решением такой задачи.
Имеем 2 datagridview с данными с екселя.
Нужно пройтись по каждому 1-му столбцу и сравнить ячейки,при совпадении записать в 2-й столбец 2-го грида например "Да" или нет если несовпало
На фото будет понятней что нужно[image]

У меня есть код который загружает данные с екселя (с уроков на ютубе взят) все работает,а вот что и как дальше сделать не знаю.
С 1 листом потыкался и за неделю научился дергать с него данные,а вот как работать с 2 сразу это пока не могу понять.
Подсобите решением буду очень признателен за помощь.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using ExcelDataReader;

namespace exelTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        DataSet result;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel 97-2003.xls|*.xls|Excel .xlsx|*.xlsx|Excel .csv|*.csv", ValidateNames = true })
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    FileStream fs = File.Open(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    IExcelDataReader reader;
                    if (ofd.FilterIndex == 1)
                        reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(fs);
                    else
                        reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(fs);
                    //reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
                    //result = reader.AsDataSet();
                    result = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration() { ConfigureDataTable = (_) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration() { UseHeaderRow = true } });
                    comboBox1.Items.Clear();
                    foreach (DataTable dt in result.Tables)
                        comboBox1.Items.Add(dt.TableName);
                    reader.Close();
                    textBox1.Text = ofd.FileName;
                }
        }

        public void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = result.Tables[comboBox1.SelectedIndex];
            // определить количество столбцов
            int n;
            n = dataGridView1.Columns.Count;
            textBox3.Text = n.ToString();
            // определить количество строк без строки заголовка
            int nt;
            nt = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
            textBox4.Text = (nt - 1).ToString();
            DataTable dt = result.Tables[0];




        }

        public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel 97-2003.xls|*.xls|Excel .xlsx|*.xlsx|Excel .csv|*.csv", ValidateNames = true })
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    FileStream fs = File.Open(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    IExcelDataReader reader;
                    if (ofd.FilterIndex == 1)
                        reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(fs);
                    else
                        reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(fs);
                    //reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
                    //result = reader.AsDataSet();
                    result = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration() { ConfigureDataTable = (_) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration() { UseHeaderRow = true } });
                    comboBox2.Items.Clear();
                    foreach (DataTable dt2 in result.Tables)
                        comboBox2.Items.Add(dt2.TableName);
                    reader.Close();
                    textBox5.Text = ofd.FileName;
                }

        }

        public void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView2.DataSource = result.Tables[comboBox2.SelectedIndex];
            // определить количество столбцов
            int n;
            n = dataGridView2.Columns.Count;
            textBox6.Text = n.ToString();
            // определить количество строк без строки заголовка
            int nt;
            nt = dataGridView2.Rows.Count;
            textBox7.Text = (nt - 1).ToString();
            DataTable dt2 = result.Tables[0];
        }

        public void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Пример работы с `DataTable`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1115342/373567)