# DataGridView принимает матрицу N x M объектов одного типа

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Упрощенная схема.
Есть объект данных:

```
   class Data
    {
        public int Digit { get; set; }
    }
```

В коде создается список данных и привязывается к DataGridView.

```
List<Data> dataList = new List<Data>()
   {
     new Data(){Digit=1},
     new Data(){Digit=2},
     new Data(){Digit=1}
   };
dataGrid.DataSource = dataList;
```

Работает правильно - в ячейках размещены объекты Data и свойство Digit привязано к свойству DataGridCell.Value. Редактирование данных в ячейке отражается на свойстве объекта Data.
Вопрос - такая схема работает для 1 колонки, а надо создать такую же схему для 10 колонок.
То есть привязать матрицу `Data[10][10]`.
Какую структуру данных надо создать для решения задачи?

Пробовал такой вариант, но выводиться не значение а имя класса

```
            dataGrid.Columns.Add( new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
            {
                HeaderText="0",
                DataPropertyName="Digit"
            } );

            dataGrid.Columns.Add( new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
            {
                HeaderText = "1",
                DataPropertyName = "Digit"
            } );
            dataGrid.Rows.Add( new object[] { new Data() { Digit = 11 }, new Data() { Digit = 21 } } );
            dataGrid.Rows.Add( new object[] { new Data() { Digit = 31 }, new Data() { Digit = 33 } } );
```

Comment: В классе Data сделайте 10 свойств.

Comment: Это и так понятно. Вопроса бы не было. Надо именно объекты. Если бы у DataGridViewCell был свой DataBindings, то все решилось бы. Но надо именно массив развернуть на Cells

Comment: `DataTable` вам может помочь.

Comment: Где тогда у DataColumn из DataTable свойство для указания  DataPropertyName, как это делается в DataGridViewColumn?

Comment: Я бы написал (или поискал готовый) контрол типа грида, к которому можно прибиндить именно матрицу объектов (не список, как у стандартного грида!). Вообще, такие есть в природе. Искать лень. Когда-то я сам писал такой для матрицы вещественных чисел. Но именно простых чисел, не объектов со свойством. Хотя это не важно

Comment: Собственно я работаю на WPF. Это случайное задание на WinForms и теперь я реально понял какая это жесть - WinFroms!

Comment: [Шматрицы в WPF](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1115342/373567), кстати с использованием той самой `DataTable`. В Winforms можно вытворять такое же самое с поправкой на пару лишних обработчиков событий для DGV, чтобы поправить ей поведение до вменяемого. Я бы может и ответил на ваш вопрос, но я его не понял.

Comment: Если любите биндинги (привязки данных) в WPF, то в Winforms [тоже такое есть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199692/373567).

Comment: @aepot Никто не понимает, что надо но все советуют. В коде "1 ответ" есть строка кода ` dataTable.Columns.Add(i.ToString(), typeof(int));` Для понимания: мне надо почти тоже, но: ` dataTable.Columns.Add(i.ToString(), typeof(Data));` В колонку привязывается не значение а СВОЙСТВО объекта.!!!

Comment: Этим кодом вы ничего не привязываете, а просто добааляете в DT колонку нужного типа. Как использовать привязку данных я вам показал. Вам осталось создать модель данных, которая будет иметь набор свойств, нужных для отображения. А строки будет представлять коллекция таких моделей. Как использовать таблицу, я вам тоже показал на примере WPF. Я не понимаю, чего вас не устраивает.

Comment: Загрузите данные в `DataTable`, потом выгрузите, когда надо будет сохранить. Не создавайте себе искусственные сложности.

Comment: Я так и не понял, winforms или wpf. Метки поставь правильно.

Comment: @Qwertiy Да WinForms! Упоминался WPF по причине, что там можно такое, а здесь никак. Причина: у всех WPF элементов есть DataContext (свой или наследственный от родителя) и там легко можно привязать объект - а здесь не получиться - у DataGridViewCell нет свойства для привязки ОБЪЕКТА.

Answer (score 1):

Как вам уже предложили в комментариях, можно использовать `DataTable`.

Допустим, имеется список объектов вашего класса: `List<Data> dataList`. Заполненный следующим образом:

```
dataList = new List<Data>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        dataList.Add(new Data { Digit = i * 10 + j });
```

Имеется `DataTable dataTable`:

```
dataTable = new DataTable();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    dataTable.Columns.Add(i.ToString(), typeof(int));
```

Теперь нужно смапить список на таблицу:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataList.Count; i += 10)
{
    var row = dataTable.NewRow();
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        row[j] = dataList[i + j].Digit;
    dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Всё, можно сделать привязку к гриду:

```
dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;
```

Когда пользователь поработает с данными в гриде и вам снова нужен список с объектами `Data`, делаем обратный маппинг:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        dataList[i * 10 + j].Digit = (int)dataTable.Rows[j][i];
```

Теперь в `dataList` обновлённые данные.

Следить за индексами - ваша обязанность. Если количество объектов в списке не кратно количеству колонок в таблице - надеюсь, сами сделаете проверки.

---

Чтобы два раза не вставать. Во избежание тормозов, используйте грид с двойной буферизацией

```
class DoubleBufferedDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    protected override bool DoubleBuffered => true;
}
```

Comment: Я реально в шоке от того насколько люди не понимают о чем спрашивают. Все что написал Alexander Petrov я давно сделал. Вопрос был о ПРИВЯЗКЕ ОБЪЕКТА И ЕГО СВОЙСТВА DIGIT К DATAGRIDVIEWCELL, чтобы в реальном времени изменения в Cell передавались в объект и его свойство Digit!!! Это происходит как надо если мы к DataSource привязываем список из Data. Но получается одна колонка, а мне надо массив КОЛОНОК призязанный к массиву Data

Comment: @proa - Я в шоке от того, насколько вы не знакомы с азами проектирования. Модели бизнес-логики должны быть отделены от моделей представления. Что я вам и показал. А вы пытаетесь сущности из одного слоя применить в другом, что совершенно неверно.

Comment: @proa - _люди не понимают о чем спрашивают_ - хех, самокритично. Вы не понимаете, о чём спрашиваете.

Comment: Еще раз: List<Data> привязываем к DataSource. Работает как надо:  свойство Digit привязано к своей колонке и редактирование этого свойства вызывает SETTER  свойства Digit на объекте Data!!!! Это поведение по умолчанию для привязки. Мне надо точно такое же поведение, но не для одной колонки, а для переменного числа (2...100). То есть объект типа MatrixRow в котором есть свойство 'List<Data> Digits'. Затем привязываем список List<MatrixRow> к DataSource и получаем массив колонок привязанных к объектам из MatrixRow.Digits. Чтобы редактирование данных вызвало setter на объекте Digit.

Comment: @proa - Ещё раз: одно свойство привязывается к одной колонке. Хотите десять колонок - сделайте десять свойств у привязанного объекта.

Comment: Ну вот и открыли наконец Америку - а то я не знал.

Comment: @proa - Ну вот и хорошо, теперь знаете.