# Не понимаю в чем ошибка DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите в чем ошибка, считает 2x2, 3x3 матрицы, но 2x3 выдает ошибки, что выход за индексы

Программа считает все положительные строки и если их нету сортирует матрицу по возрастанию

```
namespace WinAPP
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           
        }

       public class Data
        {
            public static int Value1 { get; set; }
            public static int Value2 { get; set; }
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
                int n = Data.Value1;
                int m = Data.Value2;
                dataGridView1.ColumnCount = n;
                dataGridView1.RowCount = m;
                button2.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
            int n = Data.Value1;
            int m = Data.Value2;
            int k;
            int p = 0;
            float[,] array = new float[n, m];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                {
                    array[i, j] = Convert.ToSingle(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value);
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                k = 1;
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                { 
                    if (array[j, i] <= 0)
                    {
                        k = 0; break;

                    }
                }
                if (k != 0) p++;

            }
            label1.Text = "P = " + p.ToString();
            dataGridView2.ColumnCount = dataGridView1.ColumnCount;
            dataGridView2.RowCount = dataGridView1.RowCount;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                    dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = array[i, j];

            }
            if(p <= 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                    {
                        dataGridView2.Sort(dataGridView2.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Descending);
                    }
                }
                MessageBox.Show("P <Выполнена сортировка!");
            }
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 fr2 = new Form2();
            fr2.Show();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Закрыть программу?", "Подтвердите действие", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Close();
            }
            else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
            {
                dialogResult = DialogResult.None;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1.Data.Value1 = Convert.ToInt32(row.Value);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В одном месте у вас `array[i, j]`, в другом - `array[j, i]`

Comment: он считает по строкам тогда, а мне над было по столбцам. Поэтому так он начал считать правильно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы перепутали индексы `i` и `j` при обращении к массиву.

Запомните просто, что массив - это `array[строки, колонки]` или `array[высота, ширина]`, а не наоборот.

Например вот так с счетчиками `array[i,j]`, или вот так с координатами `array[y,x]` или вот так `array[n,m]`, где `m` - ширина, а `n` - высота. В индексаторах первое всегда обозначает высоту, а второе - ширину.

И циклы перебора когда вы организовываете, получается что-то типа

```cs
for (int row = 0; row < rowsCount; row++)
    for (int column = 0; column < columnsCount; column++)
    {
        array[row, column] = ...;
    }
```

Строки и колонки для понимания просты и привычно в индексаторах видеть сначала строки, потом колонки, а не наоборот. Попробуйте привыкнуть к этому и перестанете путаться.

Comment: спасибо пересмотрел правильность и вроде проблема прошла

Comment: @ev2dz Бонус: есть еще сверхсекретная технолония - [привязка данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199692/373567). Очень сильно упрощает разработку, но почему-то 99% тех, кто пришет под Winforms, про нее не знают. Освойте эту технологию, и не сможете без нее жить, а то как вы сейчас это делаете - покажется вам сложным и непонятным.

Comment: @ev2dz [вот кстати](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1115342/373567) примерно то же самое что вы делаете, только WPF. Обратите внимание, что я там использую `DataTable`, которая к `DataGridView.DataSource` точно так же вяжется в `Winforms`, как к `DataGrid.ItemsSource` в WPF.

Comment: а если мне нужно выполнить сортировку данных элементов если P<0.
По возрастанию, так как я преобразовывал DataViewGrid, мне нужно использовать метод "Сортировки пузырьком"? Или же можно использовать 
dataGridView2.Sort, но тогда сортировка у меня почему то выполняется криво, если матрица 3x3 то 1 столбец не сортируется, остальные 2 сортируются по возрастанию

Comment: @ev2dz отсортируйте массив и перезаполните таблицу заново. Да, можете пузырьком, если хотите. Сортировать данные прямо в таблице - это медленно и неудобно, сортируйте лучше данные в массиве.

Comment: Не получается найти похожий алгоритм, сортировки по возрастанию столбцов. В интернете одни по строкам
                        for (int f = m - 1; f > j; f--)
                            if (array[i, f] > array[i, f - 1])
                            {
                                float tmp = array[i, f];
                                array[i, f] = array[i, f - 1];
                                array[i, f - 1] = tmp;

Comment: @ev2dz ну задайте тогда отдельный вопрос, покажите там свои попытки. Задача очень простая.

Comment: Добавил в конец этого, код с которым сейчас трудности, ошибки нету, но опять выход за пределы индексов

Comment: @ev2dz этот вопрос уже отвечен, удалите из него лишний код и задайте пожалуйста отдельный вопрос в отдельном посте.