# Горизонтальный вывод DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем добрый день! Создаю приложение наподобие школьного журнала (скрин ниже). Суть проблемы в том, что необходимо из базы данных MySQL вывести данные в горизонтальном виде в одну строчку (самый верхний dgv). Заранее количество записей неизвестно. Подскажите, каким способом можно выполнить данную манипуляцию. Заранее большое спасибо[image]

Comment: DGV я думаю не подходит для такого вообще, DGV нужно тогда, когда вам прямо в таблице надо редактировать данные, в остальных случаях DGV считается излишеством. Попробуйте вывести список в `FlowLayoutPanel` с горизонтальной ориентацией. А вообще я бы вам посоветовал поизучать WPF, там хоть по горизонтали, хоть по вертикали, хоть по диагонали, хоть полукругом вокруг окна можно данные вывести задом-наперед с анимацией плавного появления. Оговорюсь только, если соберетесь изучать, сразу читайте про MVVM и привязки данных. Писать код в WPF как в формах не следует, там принципиально другая система.

Comment: Вот [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1115342/373567) - там WPF, но суть та же. Обратите внимание на то, как я там работаю с `DataTable`. Для вас разница только в том, что в WPF оно `DataGrid.ItemsSource`, а в WinForms `DataGridView.DataSource`. Сконцентрируйтесь на том, как я изменяю `DataTable` и как я ее присваиваю в свойство `Data`, для вас это будет `dgv.DataSource = ...`. Можно ли использовать привязки данных в Winforms как в WPF? [Можно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199692/373567), опять же, там `BindingList`, у вас будет `DataTable`.

Comment: Задайте _конкретный_ вопрос! Сейчас непонятно, с чем именно у вас проблема. Вы не знаете, как работать с БД? Вы не знаете, как вывести данные в DGV? Вы не знаете, как настроить внешний вид DGV?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, проблема в горизонтальном(!) выводе данных. Работа с БД и стандартный вывод данных оттуда не представляет сложности.

Comment: @aepot, благодарю за ответ. Я ознакомился с Вашими ссылками. Возможно, в силу своей неопытности, из первой [ссылки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1115342/373567) я отметил для себя только метод `MainViewModel()`. Так как я не совсем понял, где именно содержится ответ на мой вопрос (горизонтальный вывод данных), то я перешёл по второй [ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199692/373567). 
Здесь я уже понял для себя, что нужно работать через создания списка, однако, я не понимаю, как при помощи кода сделать вывод данных именно горизонтальным.

Comment: @aepot, следует добавить, что мне нужно использовать DataGridView, ибо необходима функция изменения данных в БД через приложение (удаление, добавление, редактирование). 
Также хочу извиниться за свою неопытность, если что-то не так обозначил в предыдущем своём ответе.

Comment: @Takao не смотрите на вьюмодели и списки, смотрите на `DataTable` только на `DataTable`, и как я в нее добавляю и удаляю колонки и строки. Это может вам подсказать решение.

Comment: @aepot, ещё раз благодарю. Постараюсь разобраться

Comment: Повторю ещё раз. Задайте конкретный вопрос! Покажите, как вы сейчас пробуете добавить данные в DGV. Я реально не понимаю, что у вас не получается. Если добавить в грид одну строку, то она будет расположена горизонтально. То что вам и нужно.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, я хочу получить данные из таблицы БД в MySQL и записать их в DGV. При стандартном подключении к БД и вывод строк в DGV через `MySqlDataAdapter` сами строки выводятся столбиком сверху вниз. Мне же необходимо вывести строки горизонтально, как бы в одну строчку (тавтология, то всё же). Простыми словами, мне необходим вывод всех записей таблицы не в столбик, а в строку. С этим возникают трудности.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В комментариях выяснили, что нужно развернуть колонку в строку.

Считываем данные из БД в `List<T>`, где `T` - нужный вам тип (замените его в коде).

Потом создаём в `DataTable` нужное количество колонок. И переносим данные из списка в `DataTable`.

```
string sql = "select someColumn from someTable";

var list = new List<string>();

using (var con = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
    con.Open();

    using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con))
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            list.Add(reader.GetString(0));
        }
    }
}

var dt = new DataTable();
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    dt.Columns.Add(i.ToString());
}
dt.Rows.Add(list.ToArray());

dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
```

Вероятно, есть смысл убрать заголовки колонок и строк, а также последнюю пустую строку.

```
dataGridView.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
dataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
dataGridView.RowHeadersVisible = false;
```

В SQL существует операция, называемая pivot. Возможно, следует использовать этот способ. Но не зная структуры ваших данных сложно что-то сказать.

Comment: Бесконечно благодарю, мне именно это и нужно