# Можно как то перевернуть datagridview

Tags: c++, datagridview

Можно как то перевернуть datagridview
вместо дефолта (1) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
сделать вот так вот (2)

Comment: а какой компонент используется для отображения?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1257119/184217

Comment: Это C++/CLI + WinForms?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да

Comment: Что "да"? Отредактируйте вопрос, исправив метки. И покажите, как данные попадают в грид. Хотя с C++/CLI вам никто не поможет, ибо на этом языке не пишут полноценные приложения.