# WPF приложение представления матрицы на C#

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: У меня есть графический интерфейс, где есть два ComboBox для N и M, которые задают размерность таблицы]

У меня есть графический интерфейс, где есть два ComboBox для N и M, которые задают размерность таблицы

Инициализатор таблицы:

```
public void InitTable(int m, int n)
    {
        a = new DataArray(m, n);
        DataGridA.ItemsSource = a.Data.DefaultView;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.M; i++)
        { 
            for (int j = 0; j < a.N; j++)
            {
                a[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        DataGridA.CanUserAddRows = false;
    }
```

И теперь мне необходимо реализовать функции ComboBoxN/M_SelectionChanged которые принимают значения и инициализируют таблицу с нужной размерностью.
Не понимаю, как это сделать, пробовал несколько вариантов один из которых, но логически выглядит бредово и нелогично и к тому же не работает :

```
 private void ComboBoxN_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        InitTable(int.Parse(ComboBoxN.SelectedItem + ""), int.Parse(ComboBoxM.SelectedItem + ""));
    }
```

Как быть?

Comment: Вы не туда забрели. Есть готовый пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1115342/373567