# Номерация строк в DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Доброго времени суток ребят, можете мне помочь пожалуйста я много способов перепробывал

1. через конвертор
2. через свойство LoadingRow
3. через инкрементацию

помогло только через событие , но когда я хочу полученный индекс отобразить как текстовое поле в DataGrid оно мне то пустую строку выдаёт, или просто заполняет все нулями, а через конвертор пробивал , то подсчет идётся до 19 ,

вот результат через конвертор
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Нужно при добавлении строки её нумеровать

Comment: Но при этом нумерацию вести в созданной колонке

Comment: Проблема заключается в том , что не могу присвоить индекс строки в созданную колонку, при попытке добавления нумерация сбрасываеться

Comment: Для чего вам это? Ради красоты, или есть какой-либо функционал? Просто нумеруют обычно тогда, когда в этом есть смысл, например когда хотим чтоб у каждого объекта был уникальный номер, по которому дальше можем работать с ним лично. В вашем случае какой смысл этой колонки? Если чисто красота (что как по мне лишняя нагрузка), то делайте свое поведение, как показано например [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4663799/6808809). P.S. Очень специфичный у вас вкус, очень... Вырвиглазный красный цвет это просто жуть. Будь я пользователем вашего приложения, яб лучше вообще им не пользовался)

Comment: Если строк немного, то есть один лайфхак https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1115342/373567

Comment: Да с дизайном у меня проблема))), но суть не в этом просто хочеть 1) понять как это делается, 
2) что бы облегчить себе задачу в нумерувании

Comment: Строк будет много, даже очень больше 1000

Comment: В любом случае, я дал решение, использовать или не - ваше дело. 1000 это не много. Просто там задайте большое число для каунта, 999999 например, и готово.